# WordPress Order by using a meta_value not resulting in the correct order

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

There is a custom post type called `guides` and this has a meta `post_views_count`. The count is incremented each time someone visits a page of this post type. The data is being stored accurately.

Now I want to get a list of all posts ordered by the `post_views_count` so that I can see which article has been viewed the most.

Here is my query.

```php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'guides', 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_views_count',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => 0
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

**The problem is that `meta_value` in WordPress is stored as longtext, making it difficult to order a numeric value.**

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

looks like it is sorting it as text, you will have to add 'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC', in your query so that meta_value  is converted to number before sorting i guess. also try meta_value_num instead of meta_value in orderby

try

```
    // Sort by numeric meta
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```